# R stars plot - how can i depict the frame of star?

Tags: r, plot

The code i used is:

```
mycolors <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "orangeRed"))(n)
palette(mycolors)
stars(mydata[, 1:8], len = 0.9, key.loc = c(10, 1.5),nrow=2,ncol = 10, main = "", draw.segments = TRUE, cex=0.8,lty=1,lwd=0.1)
```

[my plot is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K0RJ.png)

[referencing Yang et al.,2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rl8ei.png)

So i would like to know that how can i add the frame of each petal in dashed line just like the figure in Yang et al., 2015? What will the code is?
I am very grateful!

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with `ggplot2` library:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
```

Example data:

```
df=data.frame(livestock=0.75,
              tea=0.5,
              crops=1,
              carb=0.25,
              aqua=0.66)
molten=melt(df)
> molten
   variable value
1 livestock  0.75
2       tea  0.50
3     crops  1.00
4      carb  0.25
5      aqua  0.66
```

Plot:

```
ggplot(molten, aes(x=seq(1,360,by=360/nrow(molten)),y=value)) +
  geom_bar(width=360/nrow(molten),stat='identity',position = "stack",colour=("grey90"),aes(fill=variable)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1 ,linetype="dotted")+
  geom_vline(xintercept = seq(37,396,by=360/nrow(molten)),linetype="dotted")+
  coord_polar()+
  theme_void()
```

Which gives:
[image]

Comment: i used your example and found the reminder of R:No id variables; using all as measure variables. I wonder whether i should change my data format?@Haboryme

Comment: You should edit your original post and add your data (or a sample of it) using dput(). For ggplot2, data needs to be in a long format (many answers on SO on a to get data into a long format).